# What does it mean , "on a bone top"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Coach tells to kids, who tried to attack him:

> Coach: Now, wake up, lads. Life's quick, you're slow. Life's hard **on a
>   bone top**.

What does it mean , "on a bone top"?

I find these line in *The Gentlemen 2019*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found a bit more context (this really doesn't make much sense with out more context) http://transcripts.thedealr.net/script.php/the-gentlemen-2019-Z6qk

The coach has beaten the boys, and now he is insulting them by calling them stupid.

> Kids stab, girls shoot, boys punch.
>   Grown-ups fight with their heads. That's where the real battle is.

and

> Up here, in the gray.  (gray matter is the brain)

With this context we can guess that "a bone top" is a person whose head is all bone (figuratively). That is a bone top is a stupid person.

The coach is saying "life is difficult if you are stupid."